# Toe overlap on mountain bike

Tags: 29er, toe-overlap

How common is toe overlap on 29" wheel bikes? Also, is there a way to fix the overlap by say replacing the shocks for some with more travel? Lastly, is toe overlap a major issue on a mountain bike?

Answer (score 1):

It is known some people moving to 29er's have issues with tow overlap, especially on small frames. I know when I am not using cleats, I sometimes get a bit of toe strike, less so now, but initially it was happening regularly.

Best not to try and 'fix' the overlap - the bike geometry will be negatively affected unless extreme care is taken. Its not a major issue, you get used to having to keep your feet back (where they should be for efficient riding) Clip less pedals solve the problem completely.

There is a reason the industry quickly moved to 650b. One take is one size does not fit all as the failed 29 experiment shows. The other (cynical one) is the industry needed a reason to sell more bikes, so they came up with 29er as the new "must have" for a couple of seasons then introduced the 650b and said "this one is much better again", knowing all along 650b was a better "one size for all" size.....

Comment: 'The failed 29 experiment' lol - there's a boardroom full of executives at Specialized who'll disagree with this!

Comment: @DWGKNZ Are you saying it was not an experiment,  They knew they would line their pockets by selling bikes that were a poor fit, then selling more bikes that were a better fit, or are you saying that it was an experiment and it was successful beyond their wildest dreams because it succeeded in selling many more bikes than would have been sold if 29er was a good fit.  :)

Comment: @matnz - I see 29 as an experiment, that was, can we flood the market with a generation of new bikes with questionable benefits?. I just don't agree it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how common it is. I can tell you that it's not as big a problem as you would expect.

Toe overlap only comes into play when you're making very sharp turns at low speed. Hitting your toe on the front tire would be dangerous at high speed - but at low speed, it's just annoying. And it doesn't even happen that often.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 46cm gravel bike with 170mm crank arms (it's a Surly Cross Check, it's approximately equivalent to a 50cm road bike ). Although it isn't a MTB, it's still a 29er (700c = 29er with narrower tires). Indeed, toe overlaps are  issues for me, although they are more like annoyance.

Toe overlaps mostly happen when I stop at a red light, or sudden strong braking (almost completely stop) with a sharp turn. However, when I ride the bike in trails with twisty turns, at a reasonable speed, toe overlaps have never occurred.

I think toe overlaps don't affect the riding performance. At first, it's quite annoying but it's not the end of the world. After a while, I'm used to it and I don't plan to modify my bike.

edit:
Recently I've been trying a lot of things on my bike, here's what I can tell from my experience:

- Go for thinner tires, I used 700x40 tires and toe overlaps happened more often. Afterwards, switching to 700x35 tires reduces the occurrence of the problem. Depending of the tires, 5mm tire width difference is very noticeable, since the diameter of the fully inflated tires can be significantly reduced, so the distance between the pedal axle to the tire surface is increased.
- Use clipless pedals. This might not help depending the pedalling habit while using platform pedals. When I used platform pedals, my foot position was already around the ball of the foot, so after switching to clipless I do not feel any difference. However, clipless pedals give some kind of predictability since my foot position does not change so I can guess/predict when the toe overlaps will likely to occur and I rotate the pedals backward to avoid them.

Comment: Are you using clip-in pedals?

Comment: Well, you have large wheels on a small frame. Using 700c wheels on a 48 cm bike makes this almost unavoidable (26" or 650b would help in this regard, and manufacturers are starting to use this).

Comment: @michael, I'm not, but I'm waiting for my new shoes and egg beaters to be delivered next week. batman, yes you are right, but I don't plan to follow the n+1 rule, so I'll live with the toe overlaps